# Add active class to nav li depending on url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some real hard time adding class active to the li that contains the current page the site is on. URL = http://polissagethibodeau.com/

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li id="home">
            <a href="./">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./about.php">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./services.php">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="./services.php#passenger">Car, Truck and Vans</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./services.php#large">Semi, Boats, RV and Busses</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./services.php#air">Airplanes and Helicopters</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./services.php#polishing">Aluminum and Plexiglass polishing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./photo.php">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./contact.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS I am trying to apply

```
.sf-menu > li.active > a {
  background: #c2e078;
}
```

Here is the script I am trying to use to no success.

```
$(function() {
    var path = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
    $('.nav>li>a[href="' + path + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Do you want to apply active class to only first level ***li*** or also to second level ***li*** ?

Comment: top level li as the second level are all just anchors on that page anyways.

Comment: Yes but second level **li** contains hash tag as url

Answer (score 1):

YOU can do it by two or many way. Example project 
Source [LINK](https://github.com/ashikjs/current-page-active-menu)

**1.----**

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("nav ul a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

**2.----**

here's the code if u want to use plain javascript

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

**3.----**

```
function setActive() {

    $('#nav').find('a').each(function () {
        //console.log(document.location.href)
        if (document.location.href == "http://......" + $(this).attr('href')) {
            $(this).parents("ul").removeClass("hidden-ul");
            $(this).parents().addClass("active");

        }
    });


}
window.onload = setActive;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a if statement to check if it is in the url:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var path = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
        if(window.location.href = path) {
            $('.nav>li>a[href="' + path + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No need use **if** condition. Code will find only those dom which matches current url

Answer (score 0):

Its because the HREF property of each of those links is going to be equal to a complete URL, not just `file.php`

You can get around this by using the `$=`  operator which means (ends with)

Note in the DEMO I changed the var path assignment to just `services.php`  so that it would work in the snippet.

Also, use the `$(document).ready(function() {`  trigger  to properly add a listener to an event

**Note**  I realize that this example will cause all of the links to `services.php` to have the class `active` added to them. To get around this assign a custom  class called `navlink` to each link in the navigation bar and then use

`$('.navlink[href$="' + path + '"]:parent').addClass('active');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//var path = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
  var path = 'services.php#large';
$('a[href$="' + path + '"]:parent').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
     font-size: 1.75em;
     
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
                    <ul class="sf-menu">
                        <li id="home">
                            <a href="./" >Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="./about.php">About us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="./services.php">Services</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./services.php#passenger">Car, Truck and Vans</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./services.php#large">Semi, Boats, RV and Busses</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./services.php#air">Airplanes and Helicopters</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                <a href="./services.php#polishing">Aluminum and Plexiglass polishing</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="./photo.php">Photos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="./contact.php">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: damn, this isn't even doing anything for me :(

Comment: Dont forget to include CSS class for .active and also the jQuery script file

Comment: Also I edited my answer to include the :parent  modifier on the CSS tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get previously stored url
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("active-class-url"))
    {
        strLastUrl = sessionStorage.getItem("active-class-url");
        $('.nav > li >a[href="' + strLastUrl + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
$(document).on(".nav > li > a", "click", function () {
    // Remove active class from all ancher tag
    $(".nav > li > a").parent("li").removeClass('active');
    // Add active class to currenly clicked acnher tag
    $(this).parent("li").addClass('active')
    // Store value of active calss url. So on page refresh you can get it
    sessionStorage.setItem("active-class-url", $(this).attr("href"));
})
```

Comment: sorry, not working either. Damn. What are we missing.

Comment: use console.log($(this).attr("href")) in click event. Then tell me are you getting same value of clicked anchor ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector.

Instead of this:

```
$(".nav > li > a")
```

Use this:

```
$(".nav > ul > li > a")
```

Also remove the `.` (dot) before your paths, and this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   $(".nav > ul > li > a").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.attr("href") === pathname) {
       $this.parent().addClass("active");
     }
   });
 });
```

---

### Test:

[image: path test]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.toString();
$('#home a').attr('href',url)
$('#home a').text(url)
      $('ul.sf-menu a').filter(function() {
        if (this.href != '') {
          if (this.href == url) {
          console.log(this.href)
          console.log(url)
            $(this).addClass('active');
          }
        }
      });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="sf-menu">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="./">Home</a>
    </li>
     <li id="stacksnippets">
      <a href="https://stacksnippets.net/">stacksnippets</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

try above method I hope it helps you.